# How to trigger Salesforce Connection (run data sync) with the api?

Tags: python, database, salesforce, simple-salesforce

I have linked snowflake to salesforce in the Data Manager in order to create dashboard in Salesforce Studio. **However I need to manually run a data sync whenever I update my data in snowflake**.

**Is it possible to trigger it with the API ?** I would like to **start a sync after the other step of my project end**. I know I can interact with Salesforce in python with simple-force for instance, but I didn't find how to interact with the DataManager.

My project and the finale step I want to add :

S3 (store data) -> Gitlab(load/transform to snowflake) -> Salesforce (Run data Sync)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for? [Run, Schedule and Sync CRM Analytics Data](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_rest.meta/bi_dev_guide_rest/bi_run_schedule_sync_data.htm?q=sync%20data)

You just need to add you Connector/API ID in the url like the example and send an empty request.
***https://<base url here>/services/data/v/wave/dataConnectors/<Connector/API ID here>/ingest***

You probably need to start from here, [Authorization Through Connected Apps and OAuth 2.0](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_oauth_and_connected_apps.htm)

Comment: It seems to be what I'm looking for !
I just need to do in python : `request.post(<url_in_your_exemple>)` ? 
And where can I find the dataflowid (or Connector/API ID) in salesforce ?

Comment: Right, you need to create a connected app so that you can access to the rest API. And for that you will need authentication. I will update the initial answer with the documentation page.

Comment: I'm already connect to salesforce, but what I can't find is the dataflow id.